# Is there a difference between "waiting methods"?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

In Mount and Blade you can "Wait here for some time" in a castle, a city, a town (if it has a manor I think?), and a camp. In addition you can just stand around in the field and wait.

Is there a difference between these? Other than the obvious price and safety difference, of course. Are trainers more effective in a camp than when just waiting in the field for example? Do heroes heal faster in any of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the differences you listed (price and safety), you party heals faster when waiting in a fort/town or village with a manor.  The amount of experience granted from training is solely determined by the skill of the trainer and nothing else.

There is 1 (very minor) drawback to waiting in a town/fort/manor, and that is you can't open the dialog to 'take an action' and select a new book to read.

Comment: Yeah, I must say I find it quite annoying that you can't open up any dialogs while waiting and that you have to exit a castle to talk to companions for example.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can still access the party dialog while inside a town/castle so that you can talk to your companions, just hit P while in the town/castle menu.